# android onActivityResult whith four activitys when back with data oncreate will be called

Tags: android, onactivityresult

activity_1 -->activity_2 -->activity_3 -->activity_4 use startActivityForResult,when back in activity_-1 oncreate being called but onResume not called. tell me why? thanks

Comment: Possible if your `activity_1` is no longer available in stack.

Comment: in this scenario your `onResume` will always be called (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle). Unless you're missing the call ...